# Double recognising as Int in JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to add an double value to an JSONObject, its automatically recognising as int(code below). After jsonObject.put the unitCost is converted to integer automatically to {"unitCost":100} rather than {"unitCost":100.0}. Please help i need to keep it as double.Thanks

```
Double unitCost = 100.0D;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("unitCost", unitCost);
```

Comment: check with different value like as 987.56

Comment: String is safe for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you use **[String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)**

> Strings are constant;

```
String unitCost = "100.0";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("unitCost", unitCost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not converting double into int. If the first decimal digit is 0, it won't be visible,
Change it to 100.1 , you will be able to see the double value.

Comment: i dont want to change it to 100.1. Is there any other way?

Comment: I agree with you @Sushobh.

Comment: @VishruthVAthrey Then use String..

Comment: There is actually no problem with 100.0 , the 0 is simply  invisible.

Comment: In statistics/engineering, "100" and "100.0" could mean two different things, as the later is a more accurate measurement. However, when using the JSON API, the zero after the comma will be discarded. If you really need to display the ".0", your only choice is representing it as a String.